# How to get context and view in android lifecycleobserver?

Tags: android, lifecycle, exoplayer

I want to put the code dealing with [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) into a [lifecycleOberserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver) class,but to initialize a exoplayer,I need to write code like this

```
    void prepareExoPlayer(Context context, PlayerView exoPlayerView) {
        if (context == null || exoPlayerView == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (player == null) {
            TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory();
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
            player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                    new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                            context,
                            Util.getUserAgent(
                                    context,
                                    context.getString(R.string.app_name)
                            )
                    );
            MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource
                    .Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .setExtractorsFactory(extractorsFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(videoUri);
            player.prepare(videoSource);
        }
        player.clearVideoSurface();
        player.setVideoSurfaceView((SurfaceView) exoPlayerView.getVideoSurfaceView());
        player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition() + 1);
        exoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    }
```

So I have to get context and view in lifecycleOberserver,but I can't find a way to do this,can someone help me?

Comment: How you are adding that lifecycleobserver to a lifecycle. Are you using any activity or fragment?

Comment: @AmitTiwary I use  `lifeCycle.addObserver(lifeCycleObserver)` in activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your lifeCycleObserver class constructor with activity parameter like

```
lifeCycleObserver(yourActivity param){
}
```

then use this param for context.

Comment: Thank you, I once thought lifeCycleObserver shouldn't have context as its constructor param =_=